# How to Handle Array of Objects with Images (Files or URLs) in NestJS

Tags: nestjs

I'm working on a NestJS application and I'm facing a challenge with handling an array of objects in a form-data request. Each object in the array represents an image with associated metadata like "id", "image" (which can be a File object or an image URL), "title", and "description".

I need guidance on how to handle this request effectively while allowing for the upload of new image files and updating the existing ones with URLs if they are provided.

```
[
    {
        "id": "0",
        "image": File Object or "image url",
        "title": "some title",
        "description": "some description"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "image": File Object or "image url",
        "title": "some title 1",
        "description": "some description 1"
    }
]
```

Expected Behavior:

I would like to understand how to process each object in the array based on whether the "image" is a new File object or an existing image URL. If it's a new image file, I want to handle the file upload appropriately. If it's an image URL, I want to leave it unchanged.